# Parse a variable to a key in python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I am new to python and experimenting with JSONs and here I am trying to pick values(member list) from a JSON but I have multiple clusters to pick the members from:

```
with open("/some/path/example.json") as js:
   dcJson=json.load(js)
   i=1
   print (dcJson["search"]["nodes"]["cluster{}"]["members"]).format(i)
```

How to write something so that the call will be dcJson["search"]["nodes"]["cluster1"]["members"]

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dcJson["search"]["nodes"]["cluster{}".format(i)]["members"]
```